# How do I solve the problem of “invalid active developer path” when attempting to use Git on VSCode

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, visual-studio-code

How do I fix this issue while on VS Code?

> xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

I've updated my bash profile

Comment: Have you tried [these solutions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52522565)?

Comment: xcode-select --install <-- how do I rewrite this command for VSCode?

Comment: @ManelAriapala the command you said installs or updates the Command line tools. xcrun needs to be installed. Whether VSCode uses it or Xcode, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 8):

```
xcode-select --install
```

This installs or updates Command Line Tools. It can be done manually too, by downloading the tools from Developer Website.

- [How to compile with Command Line Tools for Xcode after deleting the Xcode.app application bundle?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/260574/how-to-compile-with-command-line-tools-for-xcode-after-deleting-the-xcode-app-ap?rq=1)
- [Can't update Developer Tools on Mojave](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/341706/cant-update-developer-tools-on-mojave?rq=1)

You might need to point it to the install location of the tools too.

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Then restart the Terminal/ VSCode.

Answer (score -2):

Open Terminal, and run the following:

xcode-select --install
This will download and install the Command Line Tools package and fix the problem.