# What is xcrun and why would updating to macOS Mojave cause it to go missing?

Tags: bash, homebrew, path

I just upgraded my (Intel based) MacBookPro to macOS Mojave and now when typing `git pull` in a (Bash) shell, I now get the message:

```
xcrun: error invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

It looks like there is an `xcrun` in a Homebrew directory.

Do I need to add something to my `PATH`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`xcrun` is a tool that helps managing Xcode versions on your system. It allows you to write scripts that don't need to know where your Xcode instance or developer tools are installed.

The path to the Xcode version (or developer tools) is set/read via `xcode-select`. You can reset it via:

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

You can download the command line tools (that you're going to need if you don't have a full Xcode installed) via:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Or if you have Xcode installed, select it:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch <path_to_Xcode.app>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping the answer linked below helps, i.e.

```
xcode-select --install
```

[updating OS requires updating xcode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/374744/how-do-i-solve-the-problem-of-invalid-active-developer-path-when-attempting-to)

(It did.)